# Go vendor build tools

Tags: go, vendor

I need to use "vendoring" for tools used during our build (`github.com/mjibson/esc`, and `golang.org/x/tools/cmd/stringer`) to fulfill our source management requirements.

Our regulations require that all source code and all tools used during a build are fetched from a company-managed repository. In this case, the tools are built from source code at the beginning of the process.

Using `git submodule` to fetch the sources from GitHub.com/golang.org doesn't work, because our build environment prevents any access to external repositories.

I thought of something like vendoring, i.e. have a certain version of `esc` and `stringer` checked in to my repository, and some reference files that keep the relation between the version I'm using and the origin repository.

For open source used during the build (referenced through `import` statements), the `dep` tool does a wonderful job. But it fails when I try to vendor any of the tools.

How can I manage the usage of such external tools for Go?

Comment: can you fork the external tools as local repositories, `import` them from your local repos, and continue to use `dep`?

Comment: I tried to add a project that `import`s the two tools - but stringer is not a package and cannot be imported.

Comment: I think I misunderstood your question at first; now I think I see better what you mean;  still, you should be able to fork the tools;  e.g., for `stringer`, you can fork from `https://github.com/golang/tools/tree/master/cmd/stringer`, compile from there, and run that local version of `stringer` during your build process

Comment: ... if your SDLC regulations are strict enough, you might need to compile `go` itself from source;  I guess you could fork `https://github.com/golang/go` to do so; but then, the compiler you'd be using to do so needs to come from someplace ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `insteadOf` in your git config. What this does is allows you to specify a more standard import path but the actual URL that the repo is fetched from can be your private repo.

Refer to this thread: [Go dep with private repo](https://www.reddit.com/r/golang/comments/7ozhw7/is_there_a_way_to_make_go_dep_working_with/)

Answer (score 0):

I actually didn't read the [Package graph rules](https://github.com/golang/dep/blob/master/docs/Gopkg.toml.md#package-graph-rules-required-and-ignored) section in the [Gopkg.toml documentation](https://github.com/golang/dep/blob/master/docs/Gopkg.toml.md) thorough enough:

The `required` list is the place to add additional dependencies that are not referenced by `import` directives in the code. 
After adding my two packages and running `dep ensure`, all required source code was available in the `vendor` subdirectory.

My apologies...